# Login Admin Bypass, can anyone please hlp me how to bypass this?

Tags: authentication

can anyone please help me with this codes? how can I bypass this code? its a admin login. i tried SQL injection but it doesn't work. this is a admin login for a pubic ifi network. hope u guys can help me thanks in advance!

[login.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNUey.png)

Comment: Please avoid uploading code as an image.
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question
 Good luck 

Comment: You know it's [probably illegal where you are] to obtain unauthorized access to a machine/network that you don't own, right? (you mention `public wifi`)

Comment: its my own piso wifi i forgot the license key of it and the login credentials and when i contacted the seller of the software and the vendo they just ignored me